# Does a higher tickrate actually help in fast paced online FPSs?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, first-person-shooter

Does in CSGO specifically and other FPS in general, a higher tickrate such as 128 instead of 64 actually help or "feel better" or is it just overhyped and overshadowed by the normal networking latency? I hear a lot of people complaining when they miss their shots, that they would have hit if the tickrate was higher. Also is it true that in order take advantage of a higher tickrate, a high refreshrate monitor should be used?

Comment: The spray patterns differ a tiny bit from 64 tick, which you will only notice, if  you play at such a high level that you would even need 128 tick.

Answer (score 4):

Normal people complain, because they've heard the Pros complain.

The Pros complain because they truly notice the difference and get much more (actually not that many) shots on a 128 tick server.

Now you and me will probably never see any difference at all just because we don't have a professional's reflexes and senses. Although it happens and some shots disappear due to the tick rate it doesn't happen nearly as frequently as everyone claims.

People would complain because they don't want to admit that they aren't up to par and it was their fault they missed, not the server.

The tick rate is the amount of communications (calls) the game makes with the server per second. 128 ticks are twice as many calls than the 64, it has nothing to do with the FPS and the screen refresh rate, and MUCH more to do with your internet speed.

For instance Blizzard was rolling higher tick rate servers for Overwatch, but in the change Log it was noted that if you're on a slow internet the rate will drop so you can actually still play the game.

Comment: I will argue that it can have something to do with FPS and refresh rates _indirectly_.  If the tickrate is only 64 but you have a 144 Hz monitor you will be rendering twice as many frames as the server is actually reporting information on.  The difference wont be quite as simple as "every second frame doesn't register to the server" though, since there are a lot of things going on in the background like interpolation.  Those have more to due with latency, and therefore will likely exist to an extent regardless of tick rate.

Comment: @JMac that all depends on whether your machine is rendering at 144FPS though?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Yes, that obviously assuming your monitor is 144 Hz and your computer can run it at 144 FPS.